# Seam JNDI injection

Tags: seam, jndi

How do you inject a JNDI value in Seam? I read that you can use @Resource or @JndiInject, but it is not working.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What's your environment? @JndiInject is from JBoss Annotations, not Seam.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have an EJB as a Seam component, just use the standard InitialContext().lookup("something").

If you want to use an EJB that can be accessed from JNDI and to be able to use it as a Seam component, then its more complicated. See [this](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.1.1.GA/reference/en-US/html/configuration.html#d0e23572).